# Redirect to initial HTML page with attributes from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi

I am developing a webpage. I started from home.html and redirected through few php files. In the final php file I have an image URL.

I want to redirect to my home.html page and set the above URL as the src to a image element.

Please suggest me how to do it. A copy snippet will be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Initially I have a SRC for my IMG element. I want to set the old SRC to new SRC which I have in my php file. Please can you send a code snippet  Maha Dev ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are willing to do something like following:

```
<a href="home.html">
  <img src="some_image.jpg">
</a>
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkexyzr4/3/)

Comment: Clicking on image in fiddle will redirect to fiddle's home.html, but it will work fine with your code.

Comment: I am trying to do it as follows: echo '<a href="Age.html"><img id= "preview" name= "preview" src= "http://localhost/img/myImg.jpg"/></a>'; But it is not redirecting to home.html. It just echos the image in the same php file.

Comment: It's happening as you are putting it inside string. Do like  "<a href='Age.html'><img id= 'preview' name= 'preview' src={$src_path}/></a>"

Comment: echo '<a href="home.html"><img id= "preview" name= "preview" src=' + $src_path + '/></a>'; The echoed response is http://localhost/img/myImg.jpg0. The next solution is breaking.

Comment: I had edited my comment, try the latest comment. Also check for the quotes

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have home.html file which is used for home page. and if you php file is welcome.php file. then i have write simple script.

welcome.php file

```
<a href="home.html"><img src="write you image url here" /></a>
```

Comment: I am trying to do it as follows: echo '<a href="Age.html"><img id= "preview" name= "preview" src= "http://localhost/img/myImg.jpg"/></a>'; But it is not redirecting to home.html. It just echos the image in the same php file.